# How to get package `dired-icon` to show icon images in Dired?

Tags: dired, images, linux

I installed the package [dired-icon](https://www.topbug.net/dired-icon/) and restarted Emacs. I then ran

```
M-x dired-icon-mode
```

But no icon shows up in Dired mode and in the minibuffer the following message is shown:

```
Opened text-plain.png in external program
```

[image]

In my `init.el` file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/openwith")
;; https://github.com/emacsmirror/openwith
(require 'openwith)
;; Settings for package "openwith"
(when (require 'openwith nil 'noerror)
  (setq openwith-associations
        (list 
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("doc" "docx" "rtf")) "word" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("mpg" "mpeg" "mp3" "mp4" "avi" "wmv" "wav" "mov" "mkv")) "vlc" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("pdf")) "FoxitReader" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("bmp" "gif" "jpeg" "jpg" "png" "tif")) "xnview" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("rdp")) "Remote Desctop Connection" '(file))
     (list (openwith-make-extension-regexp '("xls" "xlsx")) "excel" '(file))
         ))
  (openwith-mode 1))
```

### Versions

Linux Mint 20

Emacs 26.3

What do I need to do, to see icons in Dired?

Comment: Can you show images in Emacs in general? I'm guessing no, from that error - in which case the question isn't about Dired or dired-icon. Sounds like you haven't done what it takes to have image support. Hopefully someone will advise you here. Please specify your OS etc., to help others help you.

Comment: Do you have the `openwith` package installed?

Comment: @FranBurstall Yes, I was installed package "openWith". I updated my post

Comment: @Drew No I'm not show image in Emacs in general

Comment: If you can't show images in your Emacs then please say that in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time - questions need to stand on their own. And in that case, please change the question and its title and tags (it's not about Dired), to indicate that that is your problem: how to set up Emacs so it shows images.

Comment: @a_subscriber, regarding Drews comment: try to open a *.png file in your Emacs, Emacs should show the picture by default as an image. If that is not working tell us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `openwith` is set to open any `.png` file with the external program `xnview`.

Remove `"png"` from the fourth `openwith-make-extension-regexp` list and reload.  Now emacs will handle the `.png`file natively if it can.

Comment: Thanks. Now show icons in dired mode